# riddle: "Forests without trees, / Mountains without height"

Tags: riddle, word

Another riddle:

> Cities without people,
> Forests without trees,
> Mountains without height,
> Rivers without water.
>
> Roads without travelers,
> Lakes with no boats,
> Frontiers wihout guards,
> A world in miniature.

What is it?

Comment: hmph... still think my version is cooler

Comment: Agreed. Might want to get rid of the lines about flat mountains and miniature world though, they point a bit too directly to the answer.